# How to get long tap, right click or such events on OpenLayers5?

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

I want to get some pointer events like

- long tap
- right click

Are there any examples or documentations for archive them?

NOTE: I put same question to "Geographic Information Systems", but I put this again to Stack Overflow because Openlayers official github recommended to post the questions to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself for long tap:

```
    var longpress = false;
    map.on("click",function(e){
        (longpress) ? alert("Long Press") : alert("Short Press");
        console.log(map.getEventCoordinate(e.pixel));
    });
    var startTime, endTime;
    map.on('pointerdown', function () {
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
    });
    map.on('pointerup', function () {
        endTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(endTime - startTime);
        longpress = (endTime - startTime < 500) ? false : true;
    });
```